# The minimum temperature that water can reach at a cooling tower

Tags: thermodynamics, humidity

I have read this sentences at a paper and I can't understand the reason:

Consider a cooling tower and read the following sentence:
[image: Cooling tower]

***"When the water enters hotter than the air, the ideal condition that the water
stream can attain is that the temperature at the exit equals the inlet air wet-bulb
temperature."***

Can anybody please explain the reason of " equals the inlet air **wet-bulb**
temperature"?

Answer (score 3):

The wet bulb temperature is defined as the temperature of a parcel of air cooled to saturation (100% relative humidity) by the evaporation of water into it, with the latent heat supplied by the parcel.  So if the air is supplying the heat to evaporate water in the cooling tower, it can only cool to its wet bulb temperature, but no lower.  This then represents the lowest it can possibly cool the water in the tower to.

Comment: But the entering water is not saturated air

Comment: I think I should assume rapid mass transfer from water to air at the entering that the water saturates at just the entering section. Am I correct?

Comment: At the ideal condition Should we consider that the air is fully saturated at the path of the heat and math exchanger device (cooling tower)?

Comment: So Does the outlet water temperature is lower than the inlet air temperatur(by considering that inlet air is not saturated)

Comment: Since the inlet air is not saturated, it can cool to its wet bulb temperature, which is lower.  This is the lowest that the water temperature can possibly get.  It would be nearly equivalent to using saturated air at a lower temperature.